# How to use key bindings on JLabel?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, key-bindings, key-events

I'm a beginer in coding with java (and in english too) and I'm trying to make a pong game with eclipse.
My Problem is that I don't know how to make moove my 2 Rackets (JLabel) by pressing differents keys on keyboard.
I first try with KeyListener but I didn't suceed, so now I try with keyBinding, I read a lot of tutorial but I don't really understood.

So How I can simply make my two rackets moove by pressing the arrows keys.

Here a part of the code :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class Pongg extends JPanel implements KeyListener {


private JLabel Racket1;                   // <----- Déclaration des JLabel/JLayeredPane ici pour pouvoir les utiliser (KeyListener)
private JLabel Racket2;                   //


public Pongg() {


    //Création de la fenetre
    JFrame fenetre = new JFrame("Fenetre");
    fenetre.setLocationRelativeTo (null);
    fenetre.setVisible(true);
    fenetre.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    fenetre.setSize(1000,600);

    //Box Main + JLayeredPane (fond noir)
    Box main=Box.createVerticalBox();
    JLayeredPane Fond = new JLayeredPane();
    Fond.setBackground(Color.black);        
    Fond.setOpaque(true);
    Fond.setVisible(true);

    main.add(Fond);
    fenetre.add(main);

    //Plateformes
    JLabel Racket1 = new JLabel();
    JLabel Racket2 = new JLabel();      

    //--->Racket 1 :        
    Racket1.setBounds(50, 200, 16, 100);   //<----- setBounds (Placer position du JLabel x,y + taille de la plateforme x,y)
    Racket1.setBackground(Color.white);
    Racket1.setOpaque(true);



    //--->Racket 2 :

    Racket2.setBounds(900, 200, 16, 100);
    Racket2.setBackground(Color.white);
    Racket2.setOpaque(true);

    Fond.add(Racket1); 
    Fond.add(Racket2);
```

EDDIT : here I tried to do it with keyListener (I have no idea how to do it with keyBinding) :

```
private Set appuye = new HashSet();

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        appuye.add(e.getKeyCode()); // On ajoute le nombre correspondant à la touche pressée à la liste
            if (appuye.contains(KeyEvent.VK_UP)) { // la liste contient-elle cette touche ? (c'est un int static, donc utilisable à partir de la classe, même sans objet)
                Racket1.setLocation(Racket1.getX(), Racket1.getY() - 16);
            }
            if (appuye.contains(KeyEvent.VK_DOWN)) {
                Racket1.setLocation(Racket1.getX(), Racket1.getY() + 16);
            }
            if (appuye.contains(KeyEvent.VK_A)) {
                Racket2.setLocation(Racket2.getX(), Racket2.getY() - 16);
            }
            if (appuye.contains(KeyEvent.VK_Q)) {
                Racket2.setLocation(Racket2.getX(), Racket2.getY() + 16);
            }
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        appuye.remove(e.getKeyCode()); // Lorsque la touche est relachée, on retire son numéro de la liste.

}
```

Comment: Third time lucky you think...

Comment: I hope yes, Iam on this code for 3 days.

Comment: `I have no idea how to do it with keyBinding)` - what do you mean you have no idea how to use key bindings? I gave you complete working code in your last question! Did you follow the link I gave you? Did you download the example code? The code even used two labels which would represent your rackets.

Comment: Yes I said that because keybindings are more complicated than keylistener and I didn't really understand how to use keybindings after the reading of the code u send me but MadProgrammer help me to adapt keyBindings to my programm and now I better understand how it works, but thank you for your answer

Comment: @Silver, so where are your follow up questions to the answer given? What part of the code did you not understand? How are we expected to read your mind guessing what you don't understand? That code also creates a custom `Action`. It then creates a binding between the KeyStroke and the Action. It get annoying when you completely ignore the help given and ask 3 questions on the same topic when not explaining what you find confusing about the help given.

Comment: Sorry if you take that for ignorance. It wasn't ignorance because I read the tutorial u send me and I understand the general structure (Action, bind of a component to a key and associate the bind to the action), but in practice for my code I didn't know how to adapt the code that u send me.

Comment: `but in practice for my code I didn't know how to adapt the code that u send me` - so where was your follow up question asking about parts of the code that you don't understand??? You don't ask a complete new question. If you don't ask a specific question how do people know how to improve the answer with additional information. Asking the same question won't give additional help. The example code given here and in the other question is very similar excecpt the other code also does range checking to keep the image in the bounds of the panel.

Answer (score 1):

There is a difference between key bindings and `KeyListener`, generally speaking, key bindings are preferred.

See [How to write a `KeyListener`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) and [How to use key bindings](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) for more details

To use the key bindings API, the first thing you're going to want is some kind of `Action` to respond to the key binding.  Since you just want two `JLabel`s to move up or down, this is actually very easy...

```
public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

    private JLabel label;
    private int yDelta;

    public MoveAction(JLabel label, int yDelta) {
        this.label = label;
        this.yDelta = yDelta;
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        System.out.println("...");
        Point p = label.getLocation();
        p.y += yDelta;
        label.setLocation(p);

        label.getParent().repaint();
    }

}
```

The next thing you'll need to do is register the key stroke with the `Action` (bind them together)

```
InputMap im = Racket1.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
ActionMap am = Racket1.getActionMap();

im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "Left.down.up");
im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_S, 0), "Left.down.down");
am.put("Left.down.up", new MoveAction(Racket1, -4));
am.put("Left.down.down", new MoveAction(Racket1, 4));
```

For example...

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Point;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
import javax.swing.ActionMap;
import javax.swing.InputMap;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.KeyStroke;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Pongg extends JPanel {

    private JLabel Racket1;                                  // <----- Déclaration des JLabel/JLayeredPane ici pour pouvoir les utiliser (KeyListener)
    private JLabel Racket2;                                  //

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            }

            JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.add(new Pongg());
            frame.pack();
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
        });
    }

    public Pongg() {

        setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        //Box Main + JLayeredPane (fond noir)
        JLayeredPane Fond = new JLayeredPane();
        Fond.setBackground(Color.black);
        Fond.setOpaque(true);
        Fond.setVisible(true);

        add(Fond);

        //Plateformes
        JLabel Racket1 = new JLabel();
        JLabel Racket2 = new JLabel();

        //--->Racket 1 :                
        Racket1.setBounds(50, 200, 16, 100);     //<----- setBounds (Placer position du JLabel x,y + taille de la plateforme x,y)
        Racket1.setBackground(Color.white);
        Racket1.setOpaque(true);

        //--->Racket 2 :
        Racket2.setBounds(900, 200, 16, 100);
        Racket2.setBackground(Color.white);
        Racket2.setOpaque(true);

        Fond.add(Racket1);
        Fond.add(Racket2);

        InputMap im = Racket1.getInputMap(WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        ActionMap am = Racket1.getActionMap();

        im.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_W, 0), "Left.down.up");
        am.put("Left.down.up", new MoveAction(Racket1, -4));
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {

        return new Dimension(1000, 600);

    }



    public class MoveAction extends AbstractAction {

        private JLabel label;
        private int yDelta;

        public MoveAction(JLabel label, int yDelta) {
            this.label = label;
            this.yDelta = yDelta;
        }

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("...");
            Point p = label.getLocation();
            p.y += yDelta;
            label.setLocation(p);

            label.getParent().repaint();
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you to take your time to help me, Iam going to try with the informations that you gave me.

Comment: Just littles things I didn't understand : do the order of where we place  public static void main(String[] args) { have an importance ? and I don't realy understand why do you place the JFrame in the public static void main(String[] args) { and finally the Event.Queue is for the utilisation of two action in the same time ?

Comment: The location of `static void main` within in you main class is unimportant, I, personally, like it at the top so I can see the entry point. I created the frame within the `main` method because a `JPanel` should not be creating it's own frame, at least not within the constructor, as you never know where you might want to place the component. `EventQueue.invokeLater` ensures that the UI is created within the context of the EDT in order to prevent possible issues and violations of the single thread nature of Swing